# Assign values into a imported data model angular

Tags: angular, typescript, model

I created a model like this:

```
export class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  faculty: string;
  academicYear: number;
  participatingEvents: Array<string>;
  myClubs: Array<{id: string, isPresident: boolean, isEventPlanner: boolean}>;
}
```

and use this model in a component to upload data in to firebase

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

   message: string;
   user1: User;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.user1.firstName = 'PRIYASHAN';
      this.user1.lastName = 'JAYASANKHA';
      this.user1.email = 'PRIYASHANSHELL@GMAIL.COM';
      this.user1.faculty = 'UCSC';
      this.user1.academicYear = 1;
      this.user1.participatingEvents = ['ABC', 'DEF'];
      this.user1.myClubs = [
         {id: 'QQQ', isEventPlanner: true , isPresident: true},
         {id: 'WWW', isEventPlanner: false , isPresident: true}
      ];

      this.af.submitData(this.user1);
    }
}
```

but it is not working my console shows

[image]

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user1` needs to be initialized even if you set a type.

```ts
user1: User = {} as User;
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this error since `user1` is undefined before you try to *set* values on it. Initialize the object before trying to access it.

```
user1: User;

ngOnInit() {
   this.user1 = new User();
   // ... rest of the code
}
```

Furthermore, you should create a constructor to initialize all these properties during objection creation. That way the code gets shorter and avoids typographical errors during development.

With these changes your code will look like:

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string,
    public email: string,
    public faculty: string,
    public academicYear: number,
    public participatingEvents: Array<string>,
    public myClubs: Array<{
      id: string;
      isPresident: boolean;
      isEventPlanner: boolean;
    }>
  ) {}
}
```

Creation of object + initialization of *its* properties

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user1 = new User(
      "PRIYASHAN",
      "JAYASANKHA",
      "PRIYASHANSHELL@GMAIL.COM",
      "UCSC",
      1,
      ["ABC", "DEF"],
      [
        { id: "QQQ", isEventPlanner: true, isPresident: true },
        { id: "WWW", isEventPlanner: false, isPresident: true }
      ]
    );
  }
```